# Windows.Storage.FileIO - How to save objects

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

So I was using Isolated Storage to save my objects locally as XML.  It worked, but now Microsoft has changed how it works.  According to this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx

> Isolated storage is not available for Windows Store apps. Instead, use the application data classes in the Windows.Storage namespaces
>   included in the Windows Runtime API to store local data and files.

I was doing it like this:

```
        var _Option = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;

        var _File = await Folder.CreateFileAsync(path, _Option);
        MemoryStream saveData = new MemoryStream();

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        x.Serialize(saveData, data,ns);

        if (saveData.Length > 0)
        {

            // Get an output stream for the SessionState file and write the state asynchronously
            using (Stream fileStream = await _File.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                saveData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await saveData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                await fileStream.FlushAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

But I don't see how to do this with the new way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [this helper class](https://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRtUtility/WinRtUtility/ObjectStorageHelper.cs), which stores any object in XML format in local/temp/roaming folder.
[Here's](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/tags/ObjectStorageHelper/default.aspx) blog post about that.

Comment: I was using a version of that helper.  However, I think Microsoft is not allowing that anymore?  I'm not 100% sure thought.  If they will still allow my app to pass then great otherwise I need a way to figure out how to use Windows.Storage

Comment: It will pass certification process. If you doubt that you can include the source rather than DLL. Use [WACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/jj572486.aspx) to test the app certification.